# Having trouble finding the correct XPath or XSLT to properly parse this XML feed

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML weather feed I'd like to use in two different ways on our digital signs. The first is for current temp and condition. The second is for a several day forecast. Using the One Call API on openweathermap.org, I can get the feed but our digital sign software is having trouble parsing the feed since it is nested.

For example, using the XPATH `//current` gives all the fields under that but all of the sub-fields of `<weather>` are concatenated into one string rather than separate attributes. The same goes for the `<temp>` fields in the `//daily` section. Is there an XPath or stylesheet I can use that would give me all of the field names under current or daily and give me the proper attributes of the weather and temp fields, such as `<temp@day>`?

Here is the full XML feed:

```
<IntegrationResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ReturnCode>OK</ReturnCode>
  <ID>FWI_SUCCESS</ID>
  <Description>Success</Description>
  <TimeStamp>2020-08-20T14:21:48.9135812-05:00</TimeStamp>
  <IsCachedData>false</IsCachedData>
  <HttpContentType>application/octet-stream</HttpContentType>
  <ResponseFormat>XML</ResponseFormat>
  <root>
    <lat>40.81</lat>
    <lon>-96.7</lon>
    <timezone>America/Chicago</timezone>
    <timezone_offset>-18000</timezone_offset>
    <current>
      <dt>1597951309</dt>
      <sunrise>1597923755</sunrise>
      <sunset>1597972672</sunset>
      <temp>83.66</temp>
      <feels_like>79.27</feels_like>
      <pressure>1013</pressure>
      <humidity>51</humidity>
      <dew_point>63.63</dew_point>
      <uvi>8.26</uvi>
      <clouds>1</clouds>
      <visibility>10000</visibility>
      <wind_speed>16.11</wind_speed>
      <wind_deg>170</wind_deg>
      <weather>
        <id>800</id>
        <main>Clear</main>
        <description>clear sky</description>
        <icon>01d</icon>
      </weather>
    </current>
    <daily>
      <dt>1597946400</dt>
      <sunrise>1597923755</sunrise>
      <sunset>1597972672</sunset>
      <temp>
        <day>83.66</day>
        <min>70.09</min>
        <max>84.09</max>
        <night>70.09</night>
        <eve>80.74</eve>
        <morn>83.66</morn>
      </temp>
      <feels_like>
        <day>81.82</day>
        <night>67.5</night>
        <eve>81.64</eve>
        <morn>81.82</morn>
      </feels_like>
      <pressure>1013</pressure>
      <humidity>51</humidity>
      <dew_point>63.63</dew_point>
      <wind_speed>11.56</wind_speed>
      <wind_deg>196</wind_deg>
      <weather>
        <id>500</id>
        <main>Rain</main>
        <description>light rain</description>
        <icon>10d</icon>
      </weather>
      <clouds>1</clouds>
      <pop>0.32</pop>
      <rain>0.16</rain>
      <uvi>8.26</uvi>
    </daily>
    <daily>
      <dt>1598032800</dt>
      <sunrise>1598010215</sunrise>
      <sunset>1598058983</sunset>
      <temp>
        <day>80.87</day>
        <min>62.96</min>
        <max>84.36</max>
        <night>66.99</night>
        <eve>79.34</eve>
        <morn>62.96</morn>
      </temp>
      <feels_like>
        <day>78.62</day>
        <night>65.59</night>
        <eve>80.02</eve>
        <morn>62.29</morn>
      </feels_like>
      <pressure>1010</pressure>
      <humidity>56</humidity>
      <dew_point>63.75</dew_point>
      <wind_speed>12.37</wind_speed>
      <wind_deg>190</wind_deg>
      <weather>
        <id>500</id>
        <main>Rain</main>
        <description>light rain</description>
        <icon>10d</icon>
      </weather>
      <clouds>90</clouds>
      <pop>0.7</pop>
      <rain>0.46</rain>
      <uvi>7.93</uvi>
    </daily>
    <daily>
      <dt>1598119200</dt>
      <sunrise>1598096675</sunrise>
      <sunset>1598145294</sunset>
      <temp>
        <day>83.32</day>
        <min>63.23</min>
        <max>88.03</max>
        <night>70.5</night>
        <eve>84.34</eve>
        <morn>63.23</morn>
      </temp>
      <feels_like>
        <day>83.57</day>
        <night>71.91</night>
        <eve>87.13</eve>
        <morn>61.66</morn>
      </feels_like>
      <pressure>1010</pressure>
      <humidity>60</humidity>
      <dew_point>68.02</dew_point>
      <wind_speed>11.34</wind_speed>
      <wind_deg>201</wind_deg>
      <weather>
        <id>501</id>
        <main>Rain</main>
        <description>moderate rain</description>
        <icon>10d</icon>
      </weather>
      <clouds>29</clouds>
      <pop>0.83</pop>
      <rain>3.12</rain>
      <uvi>7.67</uvi>
    </daily>
    <daily>
      <dt>1598205600</dt>
      <sunrise>1598183134</sunrise>
      <sunset>1598231603</sunset>
      <temp>
        <day>86.11</day>
        <min>65.91</min>
        <max>90.77</max>
        <night>71.53</night>
        <eve>86.83</eve>
        <morn>65.91</morn>
      </temp>
      <feels_like>
        <day>89.31</day>
        <night>72.54</night>
        <eve>92.08</eve>
        <morn>66.88</morn>
      </feels_like>
      <pressure>1012</pressure>
      <humidity>52</humidity>
      <dew_point>66.97</dew_point>
      <wind_speed>4.81</wind_speed>
      <wind_deg>203</wind_deg>
      <weather>
        <id>800</id>
        <main>Clear</main>
        <description>clear sky</description>
        <icon>01d</icon>
      </weather>
      <clouds>0</clouds>
      <pop>0.2</pop>
      <uvi>7.64</uvi>
    </daily>
    <daily>
      <dt>1598292000</dt>
      <sunrise>1598269594</sunrise>
      <sunset>1598317912</sunset>
      <temp>
        <day>90.05</day>
        <min>68.13</min>
        <max>93.61</max>
        <night>76.59</night>
        <eve>87.98</eve>
        <morn>68.13</morn>
      </temp>
      <feels_like>
        <day>90.18</day>
        <night>71.94</night>
        <eve>90.36</eve>
        <morn>67.39</morn>
      </feels_like>
      <pressure>1012</pressure>
      <humidity>49</humidity>
      <dew_point>68.7</dew_point>
      <wind_speed>11.81</wind_speed>
      <wind_deg>194</wind_deg>
      <weather>
        <id>800</id>
        <main>Clear</main>
        <description>clear sky</description>
        <icon>01d</icon>
      </weather>
      <clouds>0</clouds>
      <pop>0</pop>
      <uvi>8.39</uvi>
    </daily>
    <daily>
      <dt>1598378400</dt>
      <sunrise>1598356053</sunrise>
      <sunset>1598404220</sunset>
      <temp>
        <day>91.65</day>
        <min>70.93</min>
        <max>94.1</max>
        <night>73.99</night>
        <eve>86.95</eve>
        <morn>70.93</morn>
      </temp>
      <feels_like>
        <day>89.22</day>
        <night>71.37</night>
        <eve>88.34</eve>
        <morn>67.84</morn>
      </feels_like>
      <pressure>1011</pressure>
      <humidity>43</humidity>
      <dew_point>66.63</dew_point>
      <wind_speed>14.45</wind_speed>
      <wind_deg>201</wind_deg>
      <weather>
        <id>800</id>
        <main>Clear</main>
        <description>clear sky</description>
        <icon>01d</icon>
      </weather>
      <clouds>0</clouds>
      <pop>0</pop>
      <uvi>8.35</uvi>
    </daily>
    <daily>
      <dt>1598464800</dt>
      <sunrise>1598442512</sunrise>
      <sunset>1598490527</sunset>
      <temp>
        <day>90.81</day>
        <min>69.57</min>
        <max>94.19</max>
        <night>76.82</night>
        <eve>87.51</eve>
        <morn>69.57</morn>
      </temp>
      <feels_like>
        <day>88.16</day>
        <night>75.29</night>
        <eve>87.67</eve>
        <morn>65.97</morn>
      </feels_like>
      <pressure>1008</pressure>
      <humidity>42</humidity>
      <dew_point>64.85</dew_point>
      <wind_speed>13.71</wind_speed>
      <wind_deg>200</wind_deg>
      <weather>
        <id>800</id>
        <main>Clear</main>
        <description>clear sky</description>
        <icon>01d</icon>
      </weather>
      <clouds>0</clouds>
      <pop>0</pop>
      <uvi>8.36</uvi>
    </daily>
    <daily>
      <dt>1598551200</dt>
      <sunrise>1598528971</sunrise>
      <sunset>1598576833</sunset>
      <temp>
        <day>92.28</day>
        <min>68.72</min>
        <max>94.44</max>
        <night>68.72</night>
        <eve>87.24</eve>
        <morn>74.32</morn>
      </temp>
      <feels_like>
        <day>91.83</day>
        <night>66.36</night>
        <eve>85.6</eve>
        <morn>71.8</morn>
      </feels_like>
      <pressure>1007</pressure>
      <humidity>41</humidity>
      <dew_point>65.64</dew_point>
      <wind_speed>10.29</wind_speed>
      <wind_deg>252</wind_deg>
      <weather>
        <id>802</id>
        <main>Clouds</main>
        <description>scattered clouds</description>
        <icon>03d</icon>
      </weather>
      <clouds>38</clouds>
      <pop>0.19</pop>
      <uvi>8.1</uvi>
    </daily>
  </root>
</IntegrationResponse>
```

The way our signage software works, I'd need all the necessary fields in one feed - I can't mix multiple requests into one feed. I'm just needing to flatten out the feed somehow. So for current weather, I'd need a solution that gives me all of this, with all of the attributes under weather as their own fields:

```
<current>
<dt>1597951309</dt>
<sunrise>1597923755</sunrise>
<sunset>1597972672</sunset>
<temp>83.66</temp>
<feels_like>79.27</feels_like>
<pressure>1013</pressure>
<humidity>51</humidity>
<dew_point>63.63</dew_point>
<uvi>8.26</uvi>
<clouds>1</clouds>
<visibility>10000</visibility>
<wind_speed>16.11</wind_speed>
<wind_deg>170</wind_deg>
<weather.id>800</weather.id>
<weather.main>Clear</weather.main>
<weather.description>clear sky</weather.description>
<weather.icon>01d</weather.icon>
</current>
```

Additional, additional context regarding our signage software: in the layout editor you don't directly reference individual rows/items from the feed. You design one row using the field names you're able to bring in if you get the correct XPath or XSLT and design one row. It then populates a list using the available info from the feed and available space.

[image: screenshot of digital sign layout editor]

Comment: You've had two answers that have interpreted your requirements completely differently, and neither seems to be what you want.  I suggest that you [edit] your question, and add an exact example of the output you desire.   It may be that it requires XSLT, not just XPath, to generate.

Comment: Yeah just posted a hopefully useful additional context. It may need XSLT which I don't have any experience in creating. I've been able to stumble onto the correct XPath in previous cases, but this feed is different than others we've used before.

Comment: You cannot have `@` character in XML element names.  The output you ask for is possible as text, but your characterization of what you want is taking on the feel of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/234215), and we've already gone a round or two unproductively.   Bowing out.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to take multiple steps in your XPaths...

Instead of `//current`, use

```
//current/temp
```

or

```
/IntegrationResponse/root/current/temp
```

to select the `temp` element alone.

Similarly, instead of `//daily`, use

```
/IntegrationResponse/root/daily[dt="1597946400"]/temp/day
```

to select the `day` element, under the `temp` element under the `daily` element that has a `dt` child element with a string value of `1597946400`.

Comment: The issue if I use the //current/weather or //daily/temp XPath options is then I can't use the other fields under current or daily, and need to be able to.

Comment: You can access each field with dedicated absolute XPaths (from the document root, as shown above), or you can access a common ancestor with one XPath, and then use relative XPaths for individual descendents.  Either is way is possible.  For small examples such as this, single XPaths are simpler, but breaking out a common ancestor selection can help with code elegance or possibly even performance.